# Time spent on each chrome tab/website from data stored in History sqlite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, google-chrome

I am trying to find out the time spent on each tab/website by the user. 
For example if I visited youtube and watched it for 10 minutes then I should be able to see something like this
www.youtube.com    ---> 10 minutes

I already made a connection with sqlite database i.e. History file present in chrome directory and was able to run the following sql command to fetch the data:

```
SELECT urls.id, urls.url, urls.title, urls.visit_count, urls.typed_count, urls.last_visit_time, urls.hidden, urls.favicon_id, visits.visit_time, visits.from_visit, visits.visit_duration, visits.transition, visit_source.source FROM urls JOIN visits ON urls.id = visits.url LEFT JOIN visit_source ON visits.id = visit_source.id
```

So can anyone tell me which combination of column can i use to get the time spent on each website.

Please note that: visit_duration is not giving me appropriate data.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you're asking for something that is not feasible. My answer shows how to get a visit duration for a website. More than that, you want to keep track of each tab's time (the timer would pause when the tab is not selected) and this is something is not supported by Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`visit_duration` Stores duration in microseconds, you need to convert and format that number. Here is one way to show a human-readable visit duration:

```sql
SELECT urls.url AS URL, (visits.visit_duration / 3600 / 1000000) || ' hours ' || strftime('%M minutes %S seconds', visits.visit_duration / 1000000 / 86400.0) AS Duration
FROM urls LEFT JOIN visits ON urls.id = visits.url
```

Here is a sample output:

| URL | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| http://www.stackoverflow.com/ | 3 hours 14 minutes 15 seconds |

You can also use [`strftime`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) if you want more format options

Comment: The visit_duration is giving me wrong data. For example if I have 5 tab open and I am working on just 5th tab, visit_duration is being calculate for the other tabs too. i.e. I open 1st tab for 10 seconds, 2nd tab for 10sec 3rd tab for 10sec, 4th tab for 10 sec, 5th tab for 1 minute.. then for 1st tab I am getting visit_duration as 1min 40 seconds instead of 10seconds

Comment: `visit_duration` is the visit duration. It doesn't keep track of which tab is selected. If that's what you want, then I think you misunderstood the purpose of that column.

Comment: So I want duration for which I have opened a particular  website, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: @MissChanandlerBong Do you have a source?

Comment: @ChrisHappy Sorry, source for what?

Comment: @MissChanandlerBong, Whoops, I mean, do you have a source re: how the `visit_duration` field is calculated? Just trying to find out more information for a project.

Comment: @ChrisHappy you can check the source code from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/1fc707b3d4426007dac9d63dbe79eaafb4d41f4a/chrome/browser/history/visit_database.cc)